# Is Internet Explorer 11 unable to render images from QnaMaker in the channel?

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-qna-maker, web-chat

My team and I had been testing a chatbot using MS Botframework, QNAMaker and Azure services. The test is done in the Webchat Channel that is commonly default. We noticed that when the bot replies with an image in IE11, it does not render the image. It's an FAQ bot and all answers come from QNAMaker.

We tested this chatbot on other browsers like Firefox, Chrome and Edge and they all work fine. I even tried reapplying the markdown code used in QNAMAker that is ![Alternate (https://www.google.png) and nothing.

The expected result is that the image that comes from QNAMaker is rendered in the webchat channel in IE11 browser.

Comment: How is the image being sent to the channel from the bot? Is it a hero card or is it just markdown?

Comment: markdown using ![]() for images in the qnamaker portal

Comment: What Web Chat CDN bundle are you using - full, minimal, or ES5? Note, IE 11 only supports the [ES5 bundle](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/01.b.getting-started-es5-bundle).